# reindexing to the same index name but deleted

Tags: elasticsearch

es 5.5.3
java client 5.3.3  transport client

I follow these steps

- create new index
- Transfer data from original index to new index using reindex
- Delete the original index.
- Alias the new index with same name as original index

after the above steps, new index and original index are deleted accidentally

Is there anything important that I overlooked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake. Because of my Creatiing new index with an alias which is the same with original index.